# Creating an array out of a while loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two sets of arrays (a and b) both derived from different sources. For simplification they are array group a: URN[], HomeTeam[], HomeOdds[] and array group b: PINURN[], PINHomeTeam[] and PINHomeOdds[].

I want to compare the URN (a unique ref string of 6 letters) with the PINURN, find where there is a match and then create a new array which will be (initially) made up of the (common) HomeTeam. I can repeat for the other elements once I have the logic

Logically I am trying to:
1 cycle through once with the inner while loop to check all the 'pinurn' values (array a) against URN in the first line of array b,
2 if there is a match I add it the the new array c (@match*.*)
3 add one to array b and then repeat the process
I should end up with a new array c of all the matched values

However, whilst this finds the first match and outputs that into array c, it then doesn't loop round and repeatedly add the other matches to that array so I in essence just get the one variable returned rather than an array.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
##find common ground
@matchateam=[]
@matchbteam=[]
counter = 0

while smarketscounter < 100
  while counter < 100
    if @pinurn[counter] == @urn[smarketscounter]
       @matchateam << @pinhometeam[counter]
       @matchbteam << @hometeam[smarketscounter]
    end
    counter +=1
  end
  smarketscounter +=1
end
```

Comment: Why do you have a counter independent of the array? Can you edit this question to include more detail on what the variables involved contain? You've described them using a notation that's not at all Ruby, but maybe Java? Remember, `@urn.length` gives you the length of an array.

Comment: Hint: Most problems on Ruby have a solution involving [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html) so it's highly probable what you mean here is `@pinurn.each do |pin|` or something like that as the basis for your loop. It's also likely that you've created data structures that aren't very friendly to work with because of organizational issues. If you alter how you store the data you may make this process trivial because this use-case fits your structure better.

Comment: Thanks - I have edited it to try and remove unnecessary ambiguity. The counters are there so that I can move through each of the arrays... that said, I think your second comment is right. I’m not sure that arrays are really the best way to store these datasets. I am just starting and have tried to get the data into a common format from two different sources. I thought it would then be easy to create a matched table as such. I’ll have a look at Enumerable as you suggest. That’s come up a few times when I’ve been searching for a way around this!

Comment: It's not necessarily that arrays are wrong, but maybe having several independent arrays is not the way to do it. Ruby is great at transforming data from one form to another, but it does it best when you have everything organized properly to start with. A singular structure you can pass in is usually the best approach, be that an array of arrays, a hash of arrays, or otherwise.

Comment: A tiny example of supplied and expected data would be immensely helpful.

Comment: What this really needs is what we call an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you use [`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26)? For example:

```
a = [1, 3, 4]
b = [1, 4, 10]
a & b #=> [1, 4]
```